# CMD - get MAC address of iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, batch-file, cmd

Im trying to get the MAC address of my iPhone from my windows machine.

```
 GETMAC /s 10.30.114.14
```

And it returns:

> ERROR: The RPC server is unavailable

But if I try to get a MAC address of any other device (laptops and what not), I get a good address within milliseconds.

So Im asking: Is there a way to get a MAC address of an iDevice from CMD?

**I know I can look at the device settings, but that is realy not what I'm after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ping` it and then grab the MAC from the `arp` cache:

```
@echo off

set IP=10.30.114.14
ping -n 1 %IP% >nul
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('arp -a ^| find "%IP%"') do set MAC=%%a

echo MAC: %MAC%
pause
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Unrelated to the question, Ill tell you how much you helped me. I created a PHP script that pings all the addresses on the router, if ping was successful, it fetches the mac address. This took a minute. Now, it takes seconds with yout code. Thank you!

Comment: This is the final solution: "arp -a", and then "netsh interface ip delete arpcache". This is for the next check (I check every minute), it will be clean data and not from cache.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you a have the inputfile with computers or ip address list, you can give a try with batch file :

```
@echo off
Title Get IP and MAC address for remote PCs over the network using batch
Set "Copyright=by Hackoo 2021"
Title  %~nx0 %Copyright%
Mode con cols=90 lines=12
cls & color 0A & echo.
echo     ********************************************************************************
echo         Get IP and MAC address for remote PCs over the network by %Copyright%
echo     ********************************************************************************
    echo(
if _%1_==_Main_  goto :Main
:getadmin
    echo                %~nx0 : self elevating
    set vbs=%temp%\getadmin.vbs
(
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "Main %~sdp0 %*", "", "runas", 1
)> "%vbs%"
    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
goto :eof
::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Main
set "InputFile=%~dp0Hosts.txt"
set "OutPutFile=%~dp0IP-MAC.txt"
If Exist "%OutPutFile%" Del "%OutPutFile%"

If Not Exist "%InputFile%" ( 
    color 0C & echo "%InputFile%" does not exist. Please check it first ! 
    Timeout /T 8 /NoBreak>nul & Exit
)

Netsh interface ip delete arpcache >nul 2>&1

@for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%H in ('Type "%InputFile%"') do (
    Ping -n 1 %%H>nul
    @for /f "tokens=2" %%M in ('arp -a %%H ^| find "%%H"') do (
        echo %%H : %%M
        echo %%H : %%M>>"%OutPutFile%"
    )
)
If Exist "%OutPutFile%" Start "" "%OutPutFile%" & Timeout /T 1 /NoBreak>nul & Exit
```

Comment: interested in speed? `for /l %i in (1,1,254) do @start "" /b cmd /c "ping -n 1 -w 150 -a 192.168.178.%i >nul"` needs 7 seconds.